# User Control Code Not Execute Before Executing the Page Code

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

i have  a master page, `MasterPage1.master` it contains usercontrols
`header`,`headercontent` and `footer`.
i have wriiten a code in headerconten usercontrol

```
if(session["somesession"]==null)
{
Response.Redirect("Somepage.aspx");
}
```

the problem is when i'm opening a page with master page file `MasterPage1.master` without login i.e `session["somesession"]==null` then it's throwing the null reference exception for the session.It's OK cause my session has no value thats why it's throwing the exception.

*My Question is:*

> i was expecting to execute the usercontrol page code first before the
>   page code,and redirect to the `somesession` but it's not happening.
>   can someone please explain me, why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the Asp.net Lifecyle, always the Controls are loaded after the Page is loaded, and It makes sense because the Page init the load process and recursively notifies to its controls and that happen for most of the events in the asp.net lifecycle.

- Initialize
- Load view state
- Process postback data
- Load - Here asp.net creates the server control tree starting by the page.
- Send postback change notifications
- Handle postback events
- Prerender
- Save state
- Render
- Dispose
- Unload

  You could check this link for more info in the [lifecycle for asp.net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: so, you are saying that `usercontrol's` page_load event'll execute after the main page_load event?

Comment: Yes that's right, and the same for the other events as Render for example